# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-2.2-froyo, android-inflate

I am completely lost with this one. My app works perfectly on API 2.1 on my handset and through the emulator. 
I have just run it through a 2.2 emulator and I am getting a crash and this error:

```
 04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebp/com.ebp.ebpMainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at com.ebp.ebpMainMenu.onCreate(ebpMainMenu.java:58)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     ... 11 more
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:92)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     ... 21 more
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799)
04-27 20:29:41.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(341):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:284)
```

In the **main.xml** file, here is line #2

```
<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
       android:background="@drawable/mainbackground"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical">
```

and here is main line 58:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` may be the real culprit here.  Try using smaller image to see if it is a memory-related issue.

Check out these links for examples of similar issues: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - android - how many images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955188/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android-how-many-im)
  [OutOfMemory exception when loading bitmap from external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102758/outofmemory-exception-when-loading-bitmap-from-external-storage/4134307#4134307)

Comment: My biggest drawable is 44k and I've just strimmed down main.xml so it only uses 4 different layouts - am stumped!

Comment: Doh it was the background image, the resolution was too high

Comment: The same happened to me and after zillions of ways to resize bitmaps, I found out **it was a background image**!!!

Comment: @sandalone and how did you fix that ? did you move the background image somewhere else ?

Comment: @Thomas It was really long time ago and I cannot remember. Either I had a large image in /drawable folder which I moved to XHDPI folder or I implemented image-resample logic.