# Out of memory error when inflating simple xml layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, out-of-memory

I have an out if memory error reported by some users on google play that i cant seem to reproduce no matter how hard I try.

The error is shown on the line of my java file where I try to set the layout of my file.
Here is the complete dump of logcat:

```
      {java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.djodjo.android.sport.GrassrootsDragRacing/org.djodjo.android.sport.GrassrootsDragRacing.LogSheet}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
              at           com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
              at org.djodjo.android.sport.GrassrootsDragRacing.LogSheet.onCreate(LogSheet.java:20)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
              ... 11 more
              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
              ... 23 more
              Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
              at android.view.View.(View.java:2834)
              at android.view.View.(View.java:2771)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:379)
              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:174)
              ... 26 more
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/log_sheet_background_new"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--
             <ImageView  
                android:id = "@+id/topLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/top_logo3"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/help_up" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnNewLogSheet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/info_box_p1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Add New Log"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnDeleteAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/info_box_p1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnLogSheetPredictET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/info_box_p1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Predict ET"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnLogSheetListByDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/info_box_p1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Search by date"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is size of image your are loading in your layout file?

Comment: Please share the layout you are trying to inflate

Comment: can you paste the XML are you rtrying to inflate? thanks.

Comment: Check whether there's an image involved which Android tries to scale. As far as my observations go, I believe I've seen problems both with large images (file-size wise) which need to be scaled _and_ large images with smaller file size which needs to be scaled.

Comment: Could you post the layout.xml file ?

Comment: @chossen-addict how did you solve the problem

Comment: @nads the issue was apparently cause of the image sizes , there width and height being very large causing the error

Comment: @chossen-addict thnks for reply.Actually i was also getting same issue. And I need to decrease the size of images to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this error comes when size of images are larger then the either width or height of emulator. so check your images and re-size them.

for more info refer to this link[Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810250/binary-xml-file-line-2-error-inflating-class-android-widget-linearlayout)

Comment: This is the only logical reason i can also think that could be behind this error but the image is only 800 kb , what happened to "minimum memory that android is going to allocate to one app is 16 MB" thing?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but i think it is more about the size of the image then width and height cause i have tested the app on the smallest mobile i could lay my hands on but it still worked fine and the error was on mobiles of rather higher display resolution.

Comment: Boom! Thank you so much for mentioning this!

Answer (score 2):

I see this error when the app is running out of memory ie. there is a memory leak somewhere. I have made a image heavy app and only after switching to Googles new Volley framework have the error gone away.