# OutOfMemoryError in setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a bug in my application that is very hard to catch as it happens very few times (maybe once every 500 times I run the application on a real device). I have a couple custom views in the layout associated with the activity. In the setContentView() method of the activity I sometimes run into an OOME and I have no idea why?

It appears to be trying to inflate that view then from there it goes down hill. Because the problem rarely happens, is there a way I can handle this error or how can I avoid it? I am not understanding how the memory is used up in this case. Here is the stack trace

```
 Process: com.android.wallfly, PID: 31817
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.wallfly/com.android.wallfly.Tabs.CreateEvent}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #738: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #738: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)

        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2015)
        at com.android.wallfly.Tabs.CreateEvent.onCreate(CreateEvent.java:337)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3024)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3006)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
```

Here is the layout

```
<ViewFlipper
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layoutsVF">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff3a393c"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:visibility="visible">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/eventPhoto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/galleryicon"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_border" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Chose Photo"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="#4C1995"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/postedTimeTV"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#ff311760" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirmPhotoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/check_button_ab"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_confirm_bckd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/whiteBackButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="#fffbf8ff" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/blackBackButton"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/whiteBackButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/whiteBackButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/clearBackButton"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_border"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blackBackButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackBackButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/second"
    tools:context="com.android.wallfly.Tabs.CreateEvent"
    android:visibility="visible">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout" >




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <com.android.wallfly.UI_utils.CircularProgressButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapOne"
        app:cpb_paddingProgress="5dp"
        app:cpb_textComplete="@string/Complete"
        app:cpb_textError="@string/Error"
        app:cpb_textIdle="Post"
        app:cpb_cornerRadius="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blueBadgedTV"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toButtonTime"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/toButtonTime"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Who"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/divider4"
        android:background="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linedivider"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Name your event..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Description (Optional)"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="F :"
        android:id="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="T :"
        android:id="@+id/blueBadgedTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fromButtonDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_above="@+id/blueBadgedTV"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setbutton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="333333"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toButtonDate"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blueBadgedTV"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blueBadgedTV"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fromButtonDate"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fromButtonDate"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="333"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fromButtonTime"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fromButtonDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fromButtonDate"
        android:text="333"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/setbutton" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="When"
        android:id="@+id/planToAttendTV"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventDescription"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:background="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/planToAttendTV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Where"
        android:id="@+id/addToCalendarButton"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toButtonTime"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eventNameTV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
        android:background="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/addToCalendarButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linedivider"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linedivider"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/locationVF">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Address or address alias"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/confirmedLocationTV"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="#ff00c004"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Confirmed!" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventProfileVF"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fromButtonTime"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fromButtonTime"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackBadgedTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/profileButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Public"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/publicbadgebutton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/blackBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Badge: Black"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/blueBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/badgebluebutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Badge: Blue"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/greenBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/greenbadgebutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Badge: Green"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/purpleBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/purplebadgebutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Badge: Purple"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/redBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/redbadgebutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Badge: Red"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/privateBadgeButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider4"
            android:background="@drawable/publicbadgebutton"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Private"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />



    </ViewFlipper>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        android:id="@+id/space3" />

</RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="20px"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clearText"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/space100" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <Space
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="20px" />

    </ViewFlipper>


    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchHintVF"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchVF">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="20px" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searcgHintLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchhintTV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="#c79cb9ff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#ff4f4c52"
                android:textColorHint="#ff4f4c52" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X"
                android:id="@+id/cancelHint"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/searchhintTV"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textColor="#ff383838"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchhintTV"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/searchhintTV"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchhintTV" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ViewFlipper>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switchShapeViewFlipper"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radiusLayoutViewFlipper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/switch_shape_button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radiusLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:scaleX="0.4"
            android:scaleY="0.4" />



        <Space
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="20px" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/orientation_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switchShapeViewFlipper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:scaleX="0.3"
        android:scaleY="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/rotate_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switchShapeViewFlipper"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/switchShapeViewFlipper"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBarViewFlipper"
        android:alpha="70" />

      ....
```

It says the error happens at line 738 on the layout which is just a regular button widget.

***UPDATE***

The error is not when trying to inflate a custom view. The error is when trying to inflate a regular view.

Comment: What is your view? I would have to imagine it would have to be something crazy to cause a OOME. Are you sure that is where it is happening?

Comment: The view is only a button that is not even a custom button. The activity is pretty heavy weight though. It gives me an inflate exception then later an OOME.

Comment: Post your layout file and code for the custom views otherwise we're all just going to be playing guessing games.

Comment: It feels like you should start with rethinking the structure - a layout XML with 750 lines or more sounds just wrong in so many ways; I could only imagine things start going wrong when pushing so far.

Answer (score 4):

Your `OutOfMemoryError` seems to be caused when you try to process a `Bitmap`, it can be seen from these lines:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
```

I highly recommend you to read this article about [displaying bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), espessially about [loading large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and check your code if it does so.

Also, you can try to use a [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library by Square which helps a lot when working with `Bitmaps`.

UPDATE:
The problem in your case may be that you use some large image in layout, just try to use smaller one's and see if it will still persist. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810309/1889928) which is similar to yours.

Comment: I noticed that also, however I cannot imagine how this can be the case as setContentView() is one of the first methods called in the activity therefore no Bitmaps have been processed. Also, if this is the case then wouldnt this be more of a consistent problem?

Comment: Your layout is huge, so it would be much better to break it to smaller peaces using <merge> and <include> tags, also check your drawables, maybe some of them are really large.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **android:largeHeap="true"** in application tag of your manifest.