# New activity not able to start

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made an app in which user selects an image from gallery or camera. After selecting that image an web service is called which saves the image.After when I get successful response I have callend an splash screen.But when I call it it give me force close.

Java Code

```
public class sendProfilePic extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String response = CommonFunctions.makePostRequest (CaptureImage.this, "https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/Web/MobileApp/PostImsafePrflPic.aspx", "Mode=PP" + "&ID=" + personal_info.resource_id + "&ext=.jpg", f);
            Log.e ("Image Upload", "" + response);
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute ();

            commonFunctions.showProgressBar (CaptureImage.this, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute (s);
            if (s.equals ("OK")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (CaptureImage.this);
                builder.setTitle ("Sucessfull");
                builder.setPositiveButton ("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        Intent document = new Intent (CaptureImage.this, ResourceDocumentSplash.class);
                        startActivity (document);

                    }
                });

                builder.show ();
            }


            commonFunctions.showProgressBar (CaptureImage.this, false);

        }
    }
}
```

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/step_three">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jobs_on_call.app/com.example.jobs_on_call_resources.ResourceDocumentSplash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_resources.ResourceDocumentSplash.onCreate(ResourceDocumentSplash.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_resources.ResourceDocumentSplash.onCreate(ResourceDocumentSplash.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3392)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3329)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:454)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:189)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_resources.ResourceDocumentSplash.onCreate(ResourceDocumentSplash.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ResourceDocumentSplash.java

```
public class ResourceDocumentSplash extends Activity {

    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        System.gc ();
        setContentView (R.layout.resource_document_splash);
        new Handler ().postDelayed (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                i = new Intent (ResourceDocumentSplash.this, CaptureDocument.class);
                startActivity (i);

            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if your xml file is valid.

Comment: can you post ResourceDocumentSplash activity?

Comment: ya i posted the ResourceDocumentSplash activity

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` background is too large and you run out of memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown

Comment: reduce size of `step_three`

Comment: use android:largeHeap="true" in manifest.

Comment: thankyou large heap worked for me