# Application force close using RelativeLayout on Android version 4.0 ++

Tags: android, android-layout

My android application works fine using Android version 2.2 as AVD but it will be force closed when using version 4.0 and above. I have this issue when adding my layout, its fine at all version before adding it.

Here are result of my LogCat :

```
10-29 06:03:39.447: I/ActivityManager(77): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.kamusperfilman/.Splash} from pid 188
10-29 06:03:39.447: W/WindowManager(77): Failure taking screenshot for (120x180) to layer 21005
10-29 06:03:39.507: I/WindowManager(77): createSurface Window{413267c8 Starting com.example.kamusperfilman paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
10-29 06:03:39.597: D/dalvikvm(513): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
10-29 06:03:39.617: I/ActivityManager(77): Start proc com.example.kamusperfilman for activity com.example.kamusperfilman/.Splash: pid=513 uid=10040 gids={}
10-29 06:03:39.937: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2
10-29 06:03:40.017: D/dalvikvm(77): GC_CONCURRENT freed 441K, 10% free 9057K/9991K, paused 8ms+31ms
10-29 06:03:40.857: D/dalvikvm(513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 4% free 6954K/7171K, paused 63ms
10-29 06:03:40.917: I/dalvikvm-heap(513): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.574MB for 4915216-byte allocation
10-29 06:03:41.017: D/dalvikvm(513): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 11753K/12039K, paused 4ms+4ms
10-29 06:03:41.357: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0) failed with errno -2
10-29 06:03:41.427: I/WindowManager(77): createSurface Window{412f4358 com.example.kamusperfilman/com.example.kamusperfilman.Splash paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
10-29 06:03:41.467: W/InputManagerService(77): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 497 uid 10040
10-29 06:03:41.517: D/gralloc_goldfish(513): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-29 06:03:41.587: I/ActivityManager(77): Displayed com.example.kamusperfilman/.Splash: +2s37ms (total +9m19s100ms)
10-29 06:03:44.507: W/WindowManager(77): Failure taking screenshot for (120x180) to layer 21010
10-29 06:03:44.586: I/WindowManager(77): createSurface Window{412b8a00 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
10-29 06:03:44.636: I/ActivityManager(77): START {cmp=com.example.kamusperfilman/.MainActivity} from pid 513
10-29 06:03:44.636: W/WindowManager(77): Failure taking screenshot for (120x180) to layer 21005
10-29 06:03:44.656: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10005, 1) failed with errno -2
10-29 06:03:44.956: D/dalvikvm(513): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 2% free 11814K/12039K, paused 44ms
10-29 06:03:44.956: I/dalvikvm-heap(513): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 4915216-byte allocation
10-29 06:03:45.046: D/dalvikvm(513): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 2% free 11803K/12039K, paused 82ms
10-29 06:03:45.046: E/dalvikvm-heap(513): Out of memory on a 4915216-byte allocation.
10-29 06:03:45.046: I/dalvikvm(513): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-29 06:03:45.056: I/dalvikvm(513):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40997460 self=0x12810
10-29 06:03:45.056: I/dalvikvm(513):   | sysTid=513 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074082952
10-29 06:03:45.056: I/dalvikvm(513):   | schedstat=( 1004189864 881680333 170 ) utm=79 stm=21 core=0
10-29 06:03:45.056: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.056: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2717)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
10-29 06:03:45.066: I/dalvikvm(513):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-29 06:03:45.076: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at com.example.kamusperfilman.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-29 06:03:45.086: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-29 06:03:45.096: I/dalvikvm(513):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.106: D/skia(513): --- decoder->decode returned false
10-29 06:03:45.116: D/AndroidRuntime(513): Shutting down VM
10-29 06:03:45.116: W/dalvikvm(513): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kamusperfilman/com.example.kamusperfilman.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at com.example.kamusperfilman.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  ... 11 more
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  ... 23 more
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2717)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
10-29 06:03:45.236: E/AndroidRuntime(513):  ... 26 more
10-29 06:03:45.296: W/ActivityManager(77):   Force finishing activity com.example.kamusperfilman/.MainActivity
10-29 06:03:45.436: I/WindowManager(77): createSurface Window{411be800  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
10-29 06:03:45.816: W/ActivityManager(77): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{412a3288 com.example.kamusperfilman/.MainActivity}
10-29 06:03:46.476: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2
10-29 06:03:56.006: W/ActivityManager(77): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{412a3288 com.example.kamusperfilman/.MainActivity}
10-29 06:03:56.476: W/ActivityManager(77): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4132d860 com.example.kamusperfilman/.Splash}
```

here's my main layout :

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCari"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="@string/cari"/>

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCari"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCari"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/tambah" />

         <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ubah" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTentang"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"        
        android:text="@string/tentang" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnKeluar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnTentang"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTentang"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/keluar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown)

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. If you filter by "error", it's easier to see what caused the crash

Comment: is it posssible that my image is too big so its caused running out of memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your image is too large and is causing an OOM.

Any images that can be quite large, it is recommended that you load the image dynamically so that you can scale the image appropriately when loading it.

See the official notes for a quick tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html