# Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, dialog

I'm getting a crash related to XML inflation but the stack trace is not pointing me to any particular reason. 
The crash happens when I'm trying to show a dialog. Could it have anything to do with the drawable resource I'm setting as a background? The image is 9-patch.

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15849): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.exampleapp.app.views.ProgressiveHelperUIHandler.build(ProgressiveHelperUIHandler.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.exampleapp.app.activities.postscreen.PostsFragment.generateProgressiveHelper(PostsFragment.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.exampleapp.app.activities.postscreen.PostsFragment$6.onScrollStateChanged(PostsFragment.java:286)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setScrollState(RecyclerView.java:823)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$3100(RecyclerView.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.fling(RecyclerView.java:2914)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.fling(RecyclerView.java:1209)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:1703)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7393)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2462)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2468)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2177)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1482)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2470)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2125)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7578)
E/AndroidRuntime(15849):    ... 24 more
```

Line it's crashing:
`dialog.setContentView(R.layout.generic_progressive_helper);`

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/progressive_center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black_shade_3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Enter your location to groups near you!"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/got_it"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="GOT IT"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm confused about the reason for the crash. It occured once on an Android 4.1 phone and is non-reproducible. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown-cause

Comment: Can I safely assume that the memory is an out of memory crash since it's not reproducible and is happening on a lower end phone?

Comment: Just try to reduce the image size and tray again it might work...

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: " android:stateListAnimator="@null""  from my understandings this is available only from api 21. And hence this will cause crash in lower devices .Run the code after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have image (drawable-v24) in your drawable file, just remove it and add it as drawable not drawable-v24

Answer (score 0):

There is line `android:background="@drawable/pressed"` in your code and it's 5 time repeating in your code. so you have 2 options to solve this.

Place pressed.xml in your drawable folder.
Remove `android:background="@drawable/pressed"` line from your xml file.