# LayoutInflater Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, layout-inflater, fresco

Here is the deal, I have a RecycleView Adapter which inflates layout on `onCreateViewHolder`. When I try to do the following actions in order this happens:

1. Application created without any problem
2. Went into multitasking window
3. Came back to app
4. InflateException

Error is occurring at Fresco's [SimpleDraweeView](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/view/SimpleDraweeView.java) which is defined in xml.

```java
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_nobar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/photo"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/fry"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop" />
```

This is how I'm setting the adapter to RecycleView

```java
list = new ArrayList<>();
gagInfo gi = new gagInfo();
list.add(gi.setEmpty());
recList.setAdapter(new gagAdapter(list, context));
populateRecyclerView(recList);
```

```java
private void populateRecyclerView(final RecyclerView rView) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(GAGS, MODE_PRIVATE);

            Map<String, ?> allEntries = prefs.getAll();
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONObject obj;
            String keyObject;
            Boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                String entryValue = entry.getValue().toString();
                keyObject = entry.getKey();

                try {
                    JSONObject entryObject = new JSONObject(entryValue);
                    obj = entryObject.getJSONObject("nameValuePairs");
                    gagInfo gi = new gagInfo();
                    Log.d("JSON", "Processing... " + keyObject);

                    try {
                        gi.title = obj.getString("title");
                        gi.likes = obj.getString("likes");
                        gi.comments = obj.getString("comments");
                        gi.saved_date = obj.getString("saved_date");
                        gi.file_path = obj.getString("file_path");
                        gi.photoId = obj.getString("photoId");

                        list.add(gi);

                        if (first) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ca = new gagAdapter(list, context);
                                    rView.setAdapter(ca);
                                }
                            });
                            first = false;
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ca.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.remove(keyObject);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(list);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I have tried to override `onResume` in the Activity where I set Adapter to RecycleView (Main reason: Resume from `onCreate` to avoid passing null Adapter):

```java
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        String action = getIntent().getAction();
        if (action == null || !action.equals("Created")) {
            Log.v("HCA", "Restart");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeCardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            getIntent().setAction(null);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

And this is how I inflate layout in my adapter. I also tried to retry to inflate layout if it fails.

```java
@Override
    public gagViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(viewGroup.getContext());
        String card = prefs.getString("card_view", "0");
        Integer layoutID;

        if (card.equals("0")) {
            layoutID = R.layout.card_layout;
        } else {
            layoutID = R.layout.card_layout_nowhitebar;
        }

        View itemView;
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = 5;

        do try { //TODO: Why LayoutInflater fails after third try?
            itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(layoutID, viewGroup, false);
            if (!(itemView == null)) break;
        } catch (InflateException ie) {
            Log.e("LayoutInflater", ie.toString());
            if (++count == maxTries) throw ie;
        } while (true);

        return new gagViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                  at com.denizugur.ninegagsaver.gagAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(gagAdapter.java:134)
                                                                  at com.denizugur.ninegagsaver.gagAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(gagAdapter.java:25)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5779)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5003)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3193)
                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5812)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2666)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInfla
```

Comment: Please edit to show how you know the error is occurring in that class. In other words, the logcat, please

Comment: Note that, logcat says <unknown> for class but it's SimpleDraweeView

Comment: Looks like you cut off the logcat, the `Caused by` reason is important

Comment: I think ACRA cuts it off. I'll try without ACRA

Comment: It didn't change anything. I think it's same as start of the logcat

Comment: Okay, then show the XML and mention what's at line 15

Comment: Not really sure what to tell you if you are able to load other instances of that same view

Comment: Well here is the good and bad news: If I remove Line #15 everything works as expected. Bad news I need the view

Comment: Are you able to make a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: I guess. I removed every reference to SimpleDraweeView in gagAdapter and everything worked. Then enabled them again and problem is here all again.

Comment: Did you set up Fresco correctly? This includes adding the Gradle dependency, initializing Fresco and configuring ProGuard accordingly in case you've enabled it.
What's line 15 exactly? `<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView`?

Comment: I believe Fresco is working fine in some cases as it loads perfectly for the first time. Maybe when app goes to `onPause` cache deletes itself and it causes the problem. @AlexanderOprisnik

Comment: So you're saying that it works most of the time and you only see the crash sometimes? That's an important info.
How big are your images? Do you use animations? Your app could run out of memory. There is a similar question where the same happened:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown-cause

Comment: @AlexanderOprisnik Images are small in file size and loaded to SDV with `focusCrop` option. I use slide animation with `CardView`'s and SDV's are inside the `CardView` but that animation controller is after `onCreateViewHolder` and DraweeController assignment.

Comment: Do you think that animation is interfering with fresco's caching?

Comment: So you don't have animated GIFs / WebPs? Animated images are usually memory-heavy, and can lead too OOMs if not used carefully.  Please also answer my other previous questions, especially the first one.
I'm pretty sure that `CardView` animations should just work.
What images and how many (file type, size, dimensions)?
How frequently does the error occur(e.g. when you scroll a long list of images etc.)? Does it always reproduce? You should also take a look at your app's memory usage to confirm that it's a memory issue.

Comment: No, no animated images. Crash happens if I go to multitasking window or any other app then come back to app (second or third attempt). Images are not more than 500kb on storage (mostly png or jpeg, Some images are 10k px long but they are downsampled and saved before showing them). Should we move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118747/discussion-between-alexander-oprisnik-and-deniz-da-king).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass context through Adapter constructor from Activity (this) or (getActivity()). Seems like viewGroup context is null when reload.

Comment: Can you be more specific why viewGroup could be null when reloading. I have context setter in constructor.

Comment: So why you use this context -> viewGroup.getContext()?

Comment: Tried it. Nothing changes

Comment: Can you paste the line where use the adapter constructor?

Comment: You say you set the adapter to RecyclerView at onResume method above... Where?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to say I implemented `onResume` on the Activity where I set the adapter. I'll edit my question

Comment: Place breakpoint at this line recList.setAdapter(new gagAdapter(list, context)); and check context not null.

Comment: `context` is not null either in `onCreate` or `populateRecyclerView()`.