# Binary XML file line : Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, inflate-exception

I am getting `Error inflating class <unknown>` error in Android 6.0 emulators when I am trying to add foreground drawable.

My logcat :

```
Process: com.yasinkacmaz.myapp, PID: 12789
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.yasinkacmaz.myapp.adapter.NoteAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NoteAdapter.java:86)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5779)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5003)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:100)
at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1555)
at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:665)
at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:597)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
```

My related xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/row_note_cardview"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- line 14 is here --> 
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/row_note_frame"
    android:foreground="@drawable/state">

 <!-- other layout elements -->

</FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

state.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@null">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="@color/colorSelected"   />
        <stroke  android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorSelectedDark"  />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

My `build.gradle` :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

I searched Stackoverflow and yes there is so many questions about this topic and this answer guide me : [error-inflating-class-unknown-cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown-cause)

> Check your drawable/background_main i.e. the background image of your root layout - the VM runs out of memory when decoding the bitmap. Make the image dimensions smaller.

my `state.xml` causes the error but i need to use it, i tried to delete `FrameLayout` and add `android:foreground="@drawable/state"` to `CardView` but it didn't help me. But if i disable `android:foreground` attribute, i have no error .

Actually i am using that state drawable for selectable `RecyclerView` row. This happens only Android 6.0 emulators. If you want to see screenshot what it looks like in Lolipop and lower: [image]

So how can i fix this? Thanks for help !

Comment: I had a similar error like this. Please post your build.gradle file

Comment: Can you try it with any other drawable (color or something), so we can rule out problems with the drawable file itself?

Comment: @NickAsher hey Nick, I edited my question and you can see `build.gradle`  .

Comment: @Shaishav if i use foreground attribute like : `android:foreground="@color/colorSelected"` there is no error. Actually i specified my `state.xml` causes error, but i must use it for selectable `RecyclerView`

Comment: [I'm guessing here]..Is it possible the issue is caused by `<FrameLayout>` children? Can you try removing them?

Comment: @Shaishav i did it but still same error

Comment: Hey there...found the culprit (the issue was there in my build too): its the reference `android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`...if you get rid of it, it'll work. I tried it with several versions of android, but its crashing in v23 anyway.

Comment: @Shaishav thanks it solved my problem. I think Api 23 doesn't like ripples. You can post an answer and i'll edit it. maybe other guys see it easily.

Comment: Cool...I still couldn't figure out the root cause :)

Comment: @Shaishav i think adding ripple to `CardView` is the best way; and its working perfect.

Comment: Thats great...but, I think its best to open an issue with google.

Comment: @Shaishav actually you're right but i didn't tried with real device, did you tried ?

Comment: Yeah,... my v23 device was a phone only