# Using ?selectableItemBackground with a white background color

Tags: android, android-styles

I've always been using `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` for a ripple effect when a view (a `LinearLayout` for example) is clicked. I think I read somewhere that this is backwards compatible to API 14.

However, I've found that I need to use this ripple effect but with a white background. Specifically, I have a layout for a list item that will be displayed on the default color background (I'm extending from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`), so I want the list item to stand out from this background by coloring the list item plain white (`#FFFFFF`).

Here is the list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/mdu_keyline_1"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/mdu_keyline_1"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/mdu_padding_normal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/mdu_padding_normal">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The above produces the ripple effect without the white background.

If I try:

```
<FrameLayout ...
    android:background="@color/white">
```

This obviously produces a white background but without the ripple effect.

I also tried something else - and this produced a result closest to what I am looking for:

```
<FrameLayout ...
    android:background="@color/white">

    ...

    <LinearLayout ...
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground">
```

The above gave me the white background with a ripple effect. *However*, the ripple always seems to start from the center regardless of which part of the item I click.

Here are some screenshots showing the current result (ignore the shadow at the top of the list items - this is the shadow from the `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` I am using).

[image]

[image]

How could I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the foreground of your FrameLayout :

```
<FrameLayout ...
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

Comment: Hm. Wonder why I've never heard of foreground before. Works though! Thanks!

Comment: Note, it works for API 23+. For lower versions, it will have no effect

Answer (score 37):

You can create a layer-list in your drawables folder, and set this to your background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: When I am using ripple in drawable folder, at Android 6.0 this cause errors then I created a question please checkout : [binary-xml-file-line-error-inflating-class-unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862718/binary-xml-file-line-error-inflating-class-unknown). Did you tried this way in Android 6.0 ?

Comment: Does this also happen when you use this as a background drawable (instead of foreground)? I'm currently using the exact layer-list above in one of my apps, it runs fine on Android six. I'm using support libs 23.4.0.

Comment: Yes I tried to use as background. Maybe this is a CardView issue. Didnt tried to use with normal View.

Comment: In CardView you must use as android:foreground

Comment: Just applied it to a CardView as foreground, i'm not getting any errors, I'm using Android 6

Comment: Thanks I'll use it with CardView.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the selected one as it uses the `selectableItemBackground`... in the background. For example, I'm worried it may draw over a content, so it's better to use it in the background instead of in the foreground.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 5):

Ripple drawable is a `LayerDrawable` . 
So the right way to do this is :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers does work somewhat, but the following only works best for me:

In `styles.xml` add `colorControlHighlight`

```
  <style name="ExampleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    ...
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/purple_bg</item> <-- THIS LINE
    ...
  </style>

</resources>
```

In `colors.xml` add color of your choice with a bit of alpha `#77632E8E`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>

  <color name="purple_bg">#77632E8E</color>

</resources>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` set the theme on your activity (all of them)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      ...
      android:theme="@style/ExampleTheme"
      ... />
```

In the Activity's layout `main_layout.xml` set the `android:background` on the view you want the effect on:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBlock"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">
    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Both `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` works

Comment: just a small comment, theme can be applied to a single View, for example TextView and it will correctly use the colorControlHighlight property