# OutofMemory error in Android

Tags: android

I have created one game which uses images and my game is in portrait and landscape mode.
I have 2 different layout for that
When i switch from 1 orientation to other, after doing this 5 6 times, it gives force close error 
Error is like :

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Anyone know the solution? is there any way to clean up all images in switching orientation ?
thanks in advance

Comment: There are many questions has been asked earlier. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget

Comment: djk also this post has link to such issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656961/how-to-fix-error-in-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/4657285#4657285 & yeah +1 @Creative MITian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution from this link
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

i have a lots of images are setting in imageview every time orientation changes.
i just make backgorund image static and problem solved

```
private static Drawable BackgroundP;
private static Drawable BackgroundL;

if (conf.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
   if(BackgroundL == null){
      BackgroundL = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundland);
   }
} else {
   if(BackgroundP == null){
      BackgroundP = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundport);
   }
}
```

this will only set drawble one time.

hope this will help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

@djk Oh yeah, it will load drawable one time, but will also create memory leak.
This article explains why: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html