# Random Android InflateException when loading Activity

Tags: android

I am getting the following random Exception when running this Activity. I found another thread here on SO suggesting that all of my styles inherit from parent="android:Theme" but that did not help. I have run HierarchyViewer and layoutopt tools but have not found any problems with the layout file. And I have cleaned the project.

The exception is happening on the line:

```
ReceiptActivity.java:54 setContentView(R.layout.receipt_activity);
```

Here is the layout file, receipt_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background">        
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:text="@string/receipt_question"
        android:gravity="center"/>

         <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailOrSms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"            
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"            
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"             
        />

        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/receiptTypeRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emailReceipt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email Receipt"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:width="150dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            >
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/smsReceipt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Receipt"
            android:textSize="15sp" 
            android:width="150dip" 
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"             
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            >
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bar_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noThanksBtn"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        style="@style/DarkButton"
        android:text="@string/no_thanks"/>
           <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendReceiptBtn"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
        style="@style/DarkButton"
        android:text="@string/send_receipt"/>     
</LinearLayout>         
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Exception:

```
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bestfitmobile.netsecure/com.bestfitmobile.netsecure.ui.ReceiptActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at com.bestfitmobile.netsecure.ui.ReceiptActivity.onCreate(ReceiptActivity.java:54)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     ... 11 more
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     ... 21 more
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
    07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: Well, I found this. It's a known bug that was CLOSED by google. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

```
07-11 07:08:01.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15635): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

The drawable called `background` is too large. If you remove that it should load fine. Not sure how big that can be, but evidently you used an image too large.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. The png image is 320x480 and is 209kb. I have no idea why it's failing. That seems reasonably small to me. Any ideas?

Comment: That does seem reasonably small. Maybe try the solution pointed out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894818/outofmemory-error-in-android/4918344#4918344 ?