# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

I m fetching photo from gallery and display in ImageView.
But my issue is sometime is working fine and sometime is geting error.
Error is Bitmap size exceeds VM budget..

Log Error..

```
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at androidexperts.wp7.facebook.WP7FB.sharePhotoDialog(WP7FB.java:200)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at androidexperts.wp7.facebook.WP7FB.onActivityResult(WP7FB.java:269)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-01 10:14:57.098: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12863):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are trying to load large image file. Use bitmap.option methods to scale down original image by some factor say 5, so it will req. less amount of memory. and hence will not cause error. Thanks.

Comment: i m already using bitmap.option methods..

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize. set it to >1 which scales down.(set higher val)

Comment: @piyushnp, please move your comments to an answer box, so that CapDroid can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` and set it to a value >1 which will scale it down.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android) for best answer.