# android how to download an 1mb image file and set to ImageView

Tags: android, image, memory-management

I am trying to download an 1mb image file and then save to bitmap to populate an imageview.
but shows error

```
06-13 13:39:48.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1782):
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

How can I download a large image?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had been through the same issue. Before you set the downloaded bitmap to your `ImageView`, you have to compress your bitmap according to the width and height of your `ImageView`.

You have to create a scaled bitmap like this,

```
 bm1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 300, 300,true);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bm1);
```

or Compress your bitmap like this,

```
            OutputStream fOut = null;
                        File file = new File(strDirectoy,imgname);
                            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        bm1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();

                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: bm1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 300, 300,true);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bm1);
 sometimes it working and sometimes its not working. Can u tell me why?

Comment: If not try the next method I have given. This will compress and store your image. After that try to set image for imageview using the uri.