# Set Image to a ImageView from URL

Tags: android, imageview

I have Imageview and a link to the picture on the Internet. I set this picture to the ImageView like this,

```
public ImageView iv;
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String img = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(img));
```

What I want to do is download a picture from the internet to my android application and apply it to an ImageView. I want to make it as easy as possible.

helped me

```
String img_url= //url of the image
    URL url=new URL(img_url);
    Bitmap bmp; 
    bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findviewById(R.id.imageview);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: what you want to do??what is your problem???

Comment: Whats your question ?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Comment: you can't directly use like this way. You should use Universal Image Loader class.

Comment: Take a look to the [simplest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894562/2835520)

Answer (score 14):

There many libs to do this, my favourite is  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Here an example of usage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

give it a try :)

Answer (score 2):

[This method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath(java.lang.String)) create a Drawable from file path name.
[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423987/download-image-for-imageview-on-android) this answer.

Comment: you should add some snippets in case the url's are no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries available on doing this, I recommend using a library, because a they have many extra options availble.

Take [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

**Features**

- Multithread image loading
- Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disc cache, display image options, and others)
- Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file system (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process
- Possibility to customize every display image call with separated options
  Widget support
- Possibility to show an custom Image on loading, error, etc.

You have to set the options one time using:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Then, lateron you can use this anywhere in your code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String str = "http://google.com/img.jpg";

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(str, iv);
```

Ofcourse there are many other libraries you can use like [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Smart Image View](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view), [Url Image View](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) and many others.

Comment: With few modifications of the code, it really helped me. Thanks