# open part of web page in android using uri intent

Tags: android

I have an android app that lists items with url links and on clicking opens the pages using uri,

as below

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

I would like to open only for example a video or image in that page but not the whole of it. 
Is that possible in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you want to ask.
NO, it is not possible with Intent to open a part of a webpage, it will open entire page,
I suggest you to 
1. download and save the image to your drawable folder.
2. create a new actvity , and in the xml associated with that activity add a imageview
3. place your image in that imageview
4. and on the click of the link start the activity with the intent

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to either use an ImageView (load the image into it - [Download image for imageview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423987/download-image-for-imageview-on-android)) or a VideoView (as stream - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888).

It's not possible with an intent.