# Bitmap size exceeds VM budget in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I used the following code in `Gallery View` and I got the following exception. Can anyone show me where I am wrong?

```
07-18 12:45:59.774: WARN/System.err(6758): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-18 12:45:59.774: WARN/System.err(6758):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-18 12:45:59.774: WARN/System.err(6758):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
07-18 12:45:59.774: WARN/System.err(6758):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap
```

My code:

```
public boolean createReflectedImages() {
    //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
    final int reflectionGap = 4;

    int index = 0;
    for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
        try
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                            imageId,options);
            int width = originalImage.getWidth();
            int height = originalImage.getHeight();

            //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preScale(1, -1);

            //Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
            //We only want the bottom half of the image
            reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


            //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
             bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width 
              , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

            //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
            //the image plus gap plus reflection
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
            //Draw in the original image
            canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
            //Draw in the gap
            Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
            //Draw in the reflection
            canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

            //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
            Paint paint = new Paint(); 
            LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, 
                bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 
                TileMode.CLAMP); 
            //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
            paint.setShader(shader); 
            //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); 
            //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, 
                bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint); 
           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
           imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(200, 280));
           imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
           mImages[index++] = imageView;
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android ?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are the image you are loading is exceeding the RAM limit for your Android application. You should be using `inSampleSize` when you load the image in order to scale it down before it hogs all your memory.  I use this function to load all my images:

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int size){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inPurgeable = true;
        o.inInputShareable = true;
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = size;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

There are a couple extra options in there, but the big one for your problem is the `inSampleSize` which must be a power of 2. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this may help with the amount of memory used per bitmap, you can still run out of memory if you allocate *too many* bitmaps. It's not clear in the OP's question how many images are allocated.

Comment: +1 for using BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds, will save a lot of memory rather than OP's BitmapFactory.Options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

Comment: @Daniel What is the int size your passing in?

Comment: It is the pixel width and height box that the image should fit within after the resize.