# Android Error Bitmap Exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, memory, stack-trace

I written a simple application that loads a number of wallpapers(20) total from scrollview and allows the user to set them as his/her background. It installs and works fine on my device, but users have been reporting "Force Close" errors right after installing, which doesnt allow them to open the app at all! The only reported error I've gotten is this OutOfMemory error but it's quite cryptic and I'm not sure what is wrong! Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    
          ComponentInfo{com.jbsoft.BobMarleyExperience/com.jbsoft.BobMarleyExperience.BobMarleyExperi          enceActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.jbsoft.BobMarleyExperience.BobMarleyExperienceActivity.onCreate(BobMarleyExperienceActivity.java:33)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1713)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:122)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
... 27 more
```

My onCreate() method

```
//Instance vars 
    int toPhone;
    ImageView Display;
    Button SetWallPaper;
    AdView adview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Inflate the adview
        adview = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        //Create new AdRequest object
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        //Request Ad to be displayed
        adview.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Display instructions once the activity starts
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Scroll through the images below to load the wallpaper, then touch the button to set it!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        //Defining our objects
        Display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVmain);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVone);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVthree);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVfour);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVfive);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVsix);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVseven);
        ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVeight);
        ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVnine);
        ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVten);
        ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVeleven);
        ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVtwelve);
        ImageView image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVthirteen);
        ImageView image14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVfourteen);
        ImageView image15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVfifteen);
        ImageView image16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVsixteen);
        ImageView image17 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVseventeen);
        ImageView image18 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVeighteen);
        ImageView image19 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVnineteen);
        ImageView image20 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVtwenty);

        //Define Button object and set a listener for it
        SetWallPaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsetwallpaper);
        SetWallPaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Set listeners for all the images
        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Display.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
        image7.setOnClickListener(this);
        image8.setOnClickListener(this);
        image9.setOnClickListener(this);
        image10.setOnClickListener(this);
        image11.setOnClickListener(this);
        image12.setOnClickListener(this);
        image13.setOnClickListener(this);
        image14.setOnClickListener(this);
        image15.setOnClickListener(this);
        image16.setOnClickListener(this);
        image17.setOnClickListener(this);
        image18.setOnClickListener(this);
        image19.setOnClickListener(this);
        image20.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

My main layout .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:background="#808000"


    >



 <ImageView android:src="@drawable/bob2"  android:layout_weight="12" android:id="@+id/IVmain" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200dp"></ImageView>

 <HorizontalScrollView  android:layout_width="350dp"  android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="8dp" android:layout_weight="8" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">


<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob1" android:id="@+id/IVone" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob3" android:id="@+id/IVthree" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob4" android:id="@+id/IVfour" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob5" android:id="@+id/IVfive" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob6" android:id="@+id/IVsix" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob7" android:id="@+id/IVseven" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob8" android:id="@+id/IVeight" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob9" android:id="@+id/IVnine" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob10" android:id="@+id/IVten" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#FBB117" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob11" android:id="@+id/IVeleven" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>


 </HorizontalScrollView>

 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="350dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="100dp">
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="8dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

 <ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob12" android:id="@+id/IVtwelve" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob13" android:id="@+id/IVthirteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob14" android:id="@+id/IVfourteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob15" android:id="@+id/IVfifteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob16" android:id="@+id/IVsixteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob17" android:id="@+id/IVseventeen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob18" android:id="@+id/IVeighteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob19" android:id="@+id/IVnineteen" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>
<ImageView android:background="#7E2217" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bob20" android:id="@+id/IVtwenty" android:padding="3dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>

 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonsetwallpaper"
         android:text="SET AS WALLPAPER" android:drawablePadding="2dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>

 <com.google.ads.AdView

 android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:background="#ff0000"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
 ads:adUnitId="a14e8e1bbcb80eb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you might wanna show how you implement `onCreate()` and your main layout xml.

Comment: This is a duplicate, try referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android.

Comment: reduce the wallpaper bitmap size then try

Comment: @jazz how would I do that? and would that affect how it is displayed when it gets passed as a wallpaper?

Comment: @AeroDroid thank you! I will check that post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really really bad snippet of code. You should know that your application really has only a limited portion of memory on device, so you cannot load all Bitmap stuffs on memory at one time.

1. Use a `GridView`, `ListView` instead of having a lot of `ImageView`.
2. Reduce bitmap quality to a reasonable one, or you can scale them.
3. As I can see that you are trying to write something that users can pick from image list to set as `WALLPAPER`; I recommend `Gallery`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments/criticism. It really is bad coding, as I am new to Android development..but after looking up the Gallery widget I've learned that it will pretty much do the same thing I am trying to accomplish, so I will alter my code use gallery instead. Also, how would I reduce the bitmap quality, or scale them?