# Bitmap Exceed VM Budget in OnDraw Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Hi I am working on a game in which there are two main methods as usual. Ondraw for all the drawing on canvas and update for all calculations.
Now the problem is that I need to change and create new Bitmaps in Ondraw thats the requirement of the game and guess what happens? A force close with error Bitmap Size Exceeds VM Budget. Any one can help me to solve in issue in context to canvas and onDraw which is called again and again and again .

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android