# Avoiding Out Of Memory Exception in applying filters to Images (Android)

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to apply some filters on a Image. To apply the filter, i have to first create an array:

```
int[] arr = new int[image.width*image.height];// to store each pixel
```

and then i can pass it to the function which will apply the filter.

**Problem:** If i have an image greater than 500kb(around), **OOME** is there saying hello to me.

**What i tried:** Divide the full image into four parts and apply filter on each part and then join them but again i got **OOME** in the same line, i.e when creating the int array.

I dont want to compromise on the quality of Image and downsize it.

What i really want is just a **hint/logic/architecture** which can work on the large image as big as **5 mb**....

Comment: I would like to know what the method that filters the image looks like, if you don't mind?

Comment: as i told you, applying filter doesn't produce OOME but before applying i need to convert into array, here i get OOME... if you still need to see the filter code let me know, i wont mind.

Comment: I was mostly curious as to what operations you were doing on the image. Many simpler operations such as colorshifting etc. can be accomplished with a [ColorMatrix][1], in which case you don't need to create a new integer array.

[1]:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html

Comment: not only simple operations but complex operations too... i used jhlab filters now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to tile the image, like you suggested. Catch the OOME, and keep halving the size of your tiles until the array allocates successfully.

Then process each tile sequentially, re-using the array each time.

Comment: he could instead calculate the correct size of the array that would allow him to work without OOM , based on the available memory. each bitmap usually holds about width*height*4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

try using largeHeap
in manifest.xml
under application tag
add

```
android:largeHeap = "true"
```

Comment: I think this property comes from 3.0 and above... I am working in 2.2

Comment: This only applies to certain devices as well. On some devices this attribute does nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

best way to handle really large images is to use JNI .

maybe renderscript can also help, but i'm not sure about its memory limitations.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, i would consider it in two different parts.

1. how to avoid out of memory exceptions... you can refer to this link. [There is my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381617/android-i-see-heap-growing-but-i-want-it-to-stop/8382100#8382100)
2. Second is if you wanna show image that is as big as 5 MB. You can try having a buffer storage. download image in chunks one by one, save them to temp file and keep clearing the buffer storage. I haven't implemented it myself. you can give it a try.

Thanks:
N_JOY