# Write bitmap to file in chunks android

Tags: android, file, bitmap, fileoutputstream

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571906/avoiding-out-of-memory-exception-in-applying-filters-to-images-android) but you dont need to read that in order to understand it.

Now I was trying to convert bitmap into smaller parts and then save those smaller parts.

**Issue I get is,** Only the first part gets saved in the file whose size is way bigger than the full image. Below is the code I am using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Image.getHeight(); i++)
{
    fout = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(Image, 0, i,Image.getWidth(), 1);
    temp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
}
```

The Code is pretty simple but i dont understand that why the only first row gets written in the file.

**UPDATE::**
Merlin and Deepak are right. I tried now with giving different names and all the parts were successfully written to different files. Now you know the problem, should i go for the removing of header from second chunk and removing of eof from first chunk or what?

Comment: How did you check that the file has only the first row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to resist the urge to ask why on earth you are doing this as it is highly inefficient, so let's have a look.

So you are writing one line of pixels at a time but you are writing them to the same file repeatedly with the append flag set to true which is correct.

What you have missed is the fact that when you write a bitmap you are writing is self contained.  So a program reading th first line will expect that to be the entire bitmap.

This is the equivalent of having an EOF marker in a text file.  All the lines are being written but when reading it the reader gives up after the first EOF

You would need to research the [the structure of a PNG file](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) to understand more fully what is happening

Comment: Thanx, your answer looks quite ok but for the first line, as i gave a link in my question about my previous question. The thing is, i want to do some image filtering, for that i need to convert the image in int array which offcourse will give me OOME so i thought to divide the image in rows, apply filter and save them in file (reusing the variables/objects). and then read from file with some logic and add to ImageView... looks ok to me atleast.. :)

Comment: @farhan I really can't figure this one out using the standard api .  While you can easily read smaller portions of a bitmap using bitmapfactory, you can't write a segment of a bitmap.  You might need to look for a specialist library that does what you are looking for e.g libPNG

Comment: You mean to say we dont have an alternative for libPNG in sdk... and should i change my logic? I was thinking of to start working with ImageBytes.

Comment: The problem is writing the image out to a PNG file.  You could just use BitmapFactory to get a portion of your bitmap the n use bitmap.setpixels() but the problem is writing the image out afterwards.

Comment: It could be inefficient, but in my case, I need to download the file in chunks and I can’t save them in SQLite, or fetch them if the size is greater than 2Mb

Comment: @IgniteCoders storing images in a sqlite db is really bad juju.  You should create the image as a file and then save a record of the file path.  Sorry I can't be more help but I haven't done any Android stuff for years but storing images in a db any bigger than a thumbnail or avatar is (and never has been) a recommended solution.

Comment: I know. When I finish downloading the file, I create it in file system and I store only the path. But while I am downloading the file, I want to store the chunks in some place to maintained the progress.

Comment: @IgniteCoders you should use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do this.  There are lots of examples if you look

Comment: I use AsyncTask for that, but I can’t find a example or a way to store the chunks or parts of file. I want to do it temporally if the download can’t be completed for some reason like a loose of connectivity.

Comment: If it fails, you download the file again once connection is restored .  Queue the URL of the image if you have to, but don't make it complicated [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are appending compressed files (.png) one after the other, opening the resultant file will just show the first bit encoded data, which is your first row. This is logical too since the encoded image header has number of bytes comprising the encoded content and the decoders will not bother about the rest of the data in the file after end marker.

I just tried copying an .png file at the end of another, when i open the file i seen the unchanged first image!

Comment: @farhan i agree with Merlin, what you are asking for is a partial encoder for ehich you might need special libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong because you cannot append each row as png to a file. Probably it has some header stuff, so they would be appended after each append.

Comment: not necessarily, new FileOutputStream second argument is append