# Android: Unable to destroy activity

Tags: android, android-activity, destroy

I am using the following code to removes childs on every viewgroup:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.liberarMemoria();
}

public void liberarMemoria(){
     imagenes.recycleBitmaps(); 
     this.unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1));
     System.gc();
}
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
}
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
    }
    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

where the view: R.id.RelativeLayout1 is a ListView.

But doing this I have en exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {...}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeAllViews() is not supported in AdapterView
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the error log pretty much explains it: do not call `removeAllViews()` on `AdapterView`. And your code at some point meets `ViewGroup` that also is `AdapterView`.

Just rule this case out using `instanceof` check or handle exception with `try`/`catch` wrapper.

Comment: Any idea why the AddapterView doesn't support this operation? I couldn't find anything in official reference of AdapterView about it.

Comment: @r1k0, Yes, that's because AdapterView manages its children internally. You cannot add/remove them as this might break its internal state.

Answer (score 7):

Verify if your ViewGroup isn't a instance of AdapterView.

Do something like that:

```
if (!(view instanceof AdapterView<?>))
    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
```

So, on your code:

```
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
    }
    if (!(view instanceof AdapterView<?>))
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that line? Or at least check if the operation is supported with `try` and `catch`.

Also, it is a bit confusing to want to do this at all in a method called `unbindDrawables`, unless it is just a badly named method (doesn't describe what it does fully).

Are you calling all of this in `onDestroy`? If so, is there benefit from doing this? I was under the impression that the system takes care of this sort of thing for you.

Comment: onDestroy call "liberarMemoria()" and this call "unbindDrawables(..)". I must do it manually to ensure the destroy of Bitmap.

Comment: Right... but `removeAllViews` isn't necessary and is safe to remove here

Answer (score 0):

Don't call it. UnsupportedOperationException is telling you that this method is not supported or functional so you'll have to accomplish the task another way. I don't see the need in calling this anyway as the garbage collector will handle this task. Bitmap recycling should be done manually if you need to ensure it being done.

Comment: I want to recycle Bitmap and i must do manually, but what is the best way?

Comment: I can't tell you the best way without seeing all your source but you should do it in `onDestroy()` and keep track of all `Bitmap` objects used so you can `recycle()` them.