# Changing adapter values in Gridview cause an exception

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using a Gridview to show some TextViews in the inside. I have created a clear button that set a new Adapter with empty ArrayList and it works fine. When I tried to  perform the same operation in another place, an exception happen. I have tracked all my code till I have pointed out the statement that cause the problem.

Declairing the gridview at the first of the class

```
GridView gridView;
```

Got a reference in OnCreate method

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

Creating the adpater

```
String[] arrayEmpty = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayEmpty));
gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,list));//list_item is acustomized layout for the TextView
```

What I am doing in Clear() method and works fine:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,listEmpty));
```

What I am doing to set the values and DOES NOT WORK:

```
   ArrayList<String> gridList= new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            gridList.add(String.valueOf(e[i][j].getValue()));
        }
    }
//The next statement cause an Exception..Why!!?
    gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,gridList));

class solveTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> { 

    @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setProgress(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setMessage("Solving, please wait a few seconds...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
      }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... parametros) {

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             fillSudoku();
             solve();
          }
       });
       return null; 
    }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {    //update progressDialog here
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Some of the Log:

> 04-27 10:24:04.556: W/dalvikvm(7823): threadid=9: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 04-27 10:24:04.586:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7823): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 04-27
>   10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground() 04-27 10:24:04.586:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200) 04-27 10:24:04.586:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 04-27
>   10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 04-27 10:24:04.586:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7823): Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeAllViews() is not
>   supported in AdapterView 04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):
>     at android.widget.AdapterView.removeAllViews(AdapterView.java:511)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity.printSudoku(MainActivity.java:481)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity.solve(MainActivity.java:579)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity$solveTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:625)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity$solveTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 04-27 10:24:04.586:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   04-27 10:24:04.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7823):   ... 4 more 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823): Activity
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054e258 that
>   was originally added here 04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054e258 that
>   was originally added here 04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):
>     at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:258) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241) 04-27 10:24:09.849:
>   E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity.showLoading(MainActivity.java:570)
>   04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   com.etaworx.thesudokusolver.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
>   04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 04-27 10:24:09.849:
>   E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 04-27 10:24:09.849:
>   E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-27 10:24:09.849:
>   E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 04-27 10:24:09.849:
>   E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   04-27 10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 04-27
>   10:24:09.849: E/WindowManager(7823):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I think you forgot to post your stacktrace.

Comment: @Ascorbin .. I am sorry, What is the stacktrace ?

Comment: The LogCat output you get, it will contain a description of the exception. Assuming you use eclipse, there will be a lot of red colored text in your DDMS view/ the logcat window.

Comment: Should I copy and Paste it all? @Ascorbin

Comment: I have tracked the code till this statement...this is the one that makes the error @Ascorbin

Comment: it shows you're using AsyncTask in your code,post that code also. that will show where is the problem.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy .. The problem exactly in the sentence of setting the adapter "gridView.setAdapter(arrAdapter);" .. but I will post the code of AsyncTask now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `solve();` function running on main thread, doinbackground() running on background thread. change your solve() function like this

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... parametros) {
   this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         solve();
      }
   });
   return null; 
}
```

Comment: Should I replace the statement Solve with your code? I think you are right because some parameters that was declaired in the main thread are null inside solve();...What this code do exactly?

Comment: yes change code in your doinbackground . look at my answer now.

Comment: But, here is a problem. I was calling AsyncTask to be able to show the ProgressDialog but, now after making solve() works in the UIThread the progressDialog is disappeared..what should I do?

Comment: I am first, Calling a method to show the ProgressDialog in the mainThread, then invoke the solveTask().execute(); and dismiss it in the postExecution()

Comment: show the ProgressDialog in preExecution() of asynctask(). adn hide in postExecution()

Comment: I did what you told me but did not happened. I have edited the above code of the onPreExecution to show you.

Comment: your changes are ok that have to work, are you getting any exceptions or what is the problem now.

Comment: The progressDialog did not show while excecution and instantly showed up after execution and disappeared again

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask

- onPreExecute - invoked on UI thread , show progressDialog here
- doInBackground() - invoked immediately after onPreExecute. Normally starts new thread and perform the long time operations here like web hit
- onPostExecute() - invoked immediately after background thread execution in UI thread, dismiss progressDialog here

so avoid performing on UI thread in doInBackground(). [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Your logs showing that exception on removeAllViews on AdatpterView please check for this exception and the below links may useful for you

[Link1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=572), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405475/android-unable-to-destroy-activity)