# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, camera

I take an image with camera an store it in the sd card, the image stored must be upload from sd card to an imageView like that:

```
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView _image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageCarte);
_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

but i have this error:

> 05-05 08:23:20.593: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

can anyone help me. thanks

Comment: Scale the bitmap before you try and set it to the ImageView, it's too large at the moment as the error says

Comment: as I already said (yesterday) similar questions are posted at least twice a day. Please first check related questions before posting here. The answer is basically pointing to here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Comment: search this question, this question was asked 100 times and already solution available do some googling...

try this....http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Another popular: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Answer (score 0):

Using BitmapFactory in mobile is a memory consuming process. This problem will arise when you are trying to decode a lot of images continuously. 
As in java there is no option to free the memory allocated to the variable " myBitmap ". So make sure that these types of variables are set to null after using it.

Also try to use

```
System.gc() to clear the garbage collection.
```

If an error is thrown while executing "_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);" line then try to reduce the image size before displaying