# Bitmap and camera

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-camera

I didn't succeed in resolving this error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

My code is:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),op);
ImageView _image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageCarte);

int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
int height = myBitmap.getHeight();
int halfWidth = width/2;
int halfHeight = height/2;
Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, halfWidth, halfHeight, false);
_image.setImageBitmap(bmHalf);
```

Comment: This question is reposted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460588/java-lang-outofmemoryerror#comment13509696_10460588.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is a must read for handling Bitmaps in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) on your `BitmapFactory.Options` instance:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

For example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inSampleSize = 2
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),op);
ImageView _image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageCarte);
_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```