# Cycling Images - Bitmap Size Exceeds VM Budget

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-memory

I have an Activity that has a single ImageView on it, but it swaps the resourse out many times, cycling through several different high-resolution images.

I've been running into trouble with with "Bitmap Size Exceeds VM Budget" error.  I've seen [posts on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066) about manually cleaning things up in the onDestroy method, but the activity doesn't always get that far.

What can I do to cycle through a lot of big images without running out of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest recycle the bitmap of the imageView in onPause() method, and in onResume() load the image again.

Comment: This did the trick.  Reading around it sounds like manually calling recycle() on a BitMap should not be required, but making the call sure does work.  In my case, I am calling it each time I change images and not on the onPause/onResume, but that's just a detail of my Activity's flow.