# Android: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

I'm currently developing an Android app that displays images downloaded from URLs and put them in a ListView. And when it's clicked, creates a new ImageView of the image clicked. When smaller images (7kb) are clicked, it runs fine. Even runs fine up to 200kb. But anything larger than that, I get an error "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.". Looking at LogCat, it seems the problem has to do with Android running out of memory. Is there a solution to this? Or is it just a matter of having to lower the resolution of my images down to the 200kb range? Surely the image size shouldn't matter much up to 1 or 2 megabytes? It may take a bit longer to load but don't see why it would throw an error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Zoom.java

```
public class Zoom extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery_zoom);

        String selection = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image");
        Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new backgroundLoader().execute();
    }


    public class backgroundLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bmp;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions;
            bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            bmp = LoadImage(getIntent().getExtras().getString("image"), bmpOptions);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageZoom);
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
        return bitmap;

    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            return in;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

LogCat Logs

```
08-13 07:35:01.798: E/dalvikvm-heap(1132): 48064000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
08-13 07:35:01.888: E/GraphicsJNI(1132): VM won't let us allocate 48064000 bytes
08-13 07:35:01.888: D/dalvikvm(1132): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1K, 54% free 2694K/5831K, external 2229K/3423K, paused 19ms
08-13 07:35:01.888: D/skia(1132): --- decoder->decode returned false
08-13 07:35:01.888: W/dalvikvm(1132): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at com.example.example.mobile.application.gallery.Zoom.LoadImage(Zoom.java:72)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at com.example.example.mobile.application.gallery.Zoom.access$0(Zoom.java:67)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at com.example.example.mobile.application.gallery.Zoom$backgroundLoader.doInBackground(Zoom.java:54)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at com.example.example.mobile.application.gallery.Zoom$backgroundLoader.doInBackground(Zoom.java:1)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-13 07:35:01.898: E/AndroidRuntime(1132):     ... 4 more
08-13 07:35:01.908: W/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.example.example.mobile.application/.gallery.Zoom
```

Comment: "Related" column on the right side of this page didn't help?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to load a 45mb pic... That won't work on many phones

Comment: check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android

Comment: I'm on SO for several time, and I see about 2, 3 questions per day about this problem... Doing some researche before posting, you probably would know the answer already...

Comment: @IncrediApp That's the bit I don't understand, the image I'm trying to load is 800KB not 45mb?

Comment: Check Yahel's answer - that probably clarifies it

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend considering a more complex caching method to make sure you never reach the VM's memory limit. A brilliant place for resources is Android's own advance lessons site. The most critical part of the tutorial is to create an LRUCache which is bounded to be a percentage of the VM's memory limit.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know that your 200Kb is a compressed jpg format. Android stores the images in a bitmap non compressed format. Depending on the size of your photo it can add up to several megabytes per photo.

To try to minimize the problem you can take a look at the BitmapFacotry insamplesize method :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

It allows you to open an image but in a lower resolution (by powers of two).

Also try to agressively call :

```
mybitmap = null;
System.gc;
System.runFinalization;
System.gc;
```

Every time you can.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts

1. Don't keep a reference to the bitmap within AsyncTask, use it properly by defining Bitmap as param, not Void. Study [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).
2. You may need to recycle bitmaps. See Android developer training [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to handle bitmaps.
3. Study memory analysis tool (MAT) [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).