# GridLayout in Android2.3 not worked in Android ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, grid-layout

I develop one application in Android 4.0. In my application i use Grid Layout It works fine on Android 4.0 device but when i run on Android 2.3 device it gives Exception.

I include support jar library for v7 and v13 in my project.

I fount following Exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class GridLayout
```

How to solve this problem ? any one have any Idea ?

Comment: Logcat output always require in case of exception in Android.

Comment: i thing this is memory issue. you have very big size images in your code. check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12636650/1168654, and put your all code and log here.

Comment: Why not use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)? Here is a guide how to use it [Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). As far as I understand GridLayout is not included in support libraries, so implementing them won't help you

Comment: no i have no any Heavy Image, In GridLayout i only puts buttons without images

Comment: In my application i want to use GridLayout, my layout is not possible with GridView.

Comment: this is out of range ans. can you read question first?? what he want??

Comment: put your call code here.

Comment: ORLY? I see Error inflating class GridLayout