# Why does my application crash when a particular image is used?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, logcat, android-logcat

I have a workable codes that uses ImageView in the layout. The application could be run successfully before I restart my Eclipse. After that, my application crash whenever I uses the particular image. I tried replacing the image with another image, and it could run successfully. The image that caused my app to crash has a dimension of 608 x 2964 and it is a PNG file.

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I don't really understand what is written in the LogCat because I am new in Android. Appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks.

Here is the link to my LogCat : http://pastie.org/pastes/5053152/text?key=zg7tbpuj9zqvlje4v6aczq

This is my ImageView.

```
<ImageView
android:contentDescription="@string/image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"     
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/about_mj" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto

and

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

will help you alot

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and then pick the best answer. 

By the way, all I did is setContentView to the layout that contained this large image. So could I use the Bitmap method to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes you should. large bitmaps should be handled through code.

Comment: Another possible situtation is you placed your image in the mdpi folder and called it in a xhdpi phone/emulator. this will scale the bitmap size to 200%

Comment: thanks for the hint. i definitely placed my image in the wrong folder. i placed my image in the hdpi folder and called it in a xhdpi phone/emulator. the problem is solved when i transferred the image to the hdpi folder. thanks @WillingLearner for your help :)

Also, thanks everyone for your response, and I will use the links given to me to help me if i ever encounter the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly visible from log that your image is to large and causing

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Optimize your image.

Comment: It seems that my image is definitely too large. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the follwing error is the problem

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Take a look at the follwing post. It has multiple possible solutions to fix this problem:
[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at the post and try to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it shows OutOMemoryError and it shows inflateException in XML(Layout) file at line number 44. I think you are using some drawable in layout which may not get properly assigned values.

Comment: My ImageView is at line 44. Did i miss out anything in my layout?