# How to Minimize Leaks in Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am loading lots of bitmaps in every activity. I was getting lots of “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"  after switching between activities. My app is mostly on potrait orientation.

I tried many solutions and found a relatively [better approach in one of the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android/6779067?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000#6779067) on this website.

> First, set the “id” attribute on the parent view of your XML layout:
>
> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>  android:id="@+id/RootView"
>  >
> ```
>
> Then, in the onDestroy() method of your Activity, call the
> unbindDrawables() method passing a refence to the parent View and then
> do a System.gc()
>
> ```
> @Override
>     protected void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>
>     unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RootView));
>     System.gc();
>     }
>
>     private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
>         if (view.getBackground() != null) {
>         view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
>         }
>         if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
>             for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
>             unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
>             }
>         ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
>         }
>     }
> ```

But it does not completely remove `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Now I randomly get this memory exception. I have read a few posts stating that for completely getting rid of this issue you have to load bitmaps from code and release them in activity onDestroy which in my case is not a practical solution because I am loading lots of bitmaps.

Does someone have any better solution to this problem?

Comment: How are you loading/storing your bitmaps?

Comment: Try using ddms to analyze your memory leaks.

Comment: i have set my images through xml only and that images are in drawable folder.

Comment: i have got the same error but it tried to use Bitmap to set images to imageview and trying to recycle it. Still getting OOM!

Comment: I think the problem is you rely on onDestroy() which is rarely, if at all, called. The documentation reads you are not guaranteed onDestroy will be called, sometimes the system just kills your app without even calling it. Maybe you should have placed this code in onPause/onStop

Comment: @J. K., Android dont call onStop when Low-Memory occurs.