# Android Out of Memory Error while loading Wallpaper

Tags: android

I am creating my first Android App and for some reason I am getting Out Of Memory Error in the log saying 'No memory load current wallpaper'.  The funny thing is, my app doesn't even have any wallpapers to load.  I could not find any information on this problem.  Have you experienced this in your Android app?  Any ideas to what you did to fix it?

Here is the stack:

```
05-01 13:33:32.796: I/dalvikvm(65): "android.server.ServerThread" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
05-01 13:33:32.796: I/dalvikvm(65):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4062f658 self=0x1452f0
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   | sysTid=78 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1332240
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   | schedstat=( 192509168074 60642217424 29772 ) utm=16633 stm=2617 core=0
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFileDescriptor(Native Method)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:568)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:274)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:229)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.app.WallpaperManager.getFastDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:420)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.updateWallpaperLocked(ImageWallpaper.java:272)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine$WallpaperObserver.onReceive(ImageWallpaper.java:96)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:716)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-01 13:33:32.806: I/dalvikvm(65):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:576)
05-01 13:33:32.806: D/skia(65): --- decoder->decode returned false
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65): No memory load current wallpaper
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFileDescriptor(Native Method)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:568)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:274)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:229)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.app.WallpaperManager.getFastDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:420)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine.updateWallpaperLocked(ImageWallpaper.java:272)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at com.android.internal.service.wallpaper.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine$WallpaperObserver.onReceive(ImageWallpaper.java:96)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:716)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-01 13:33:32.817: W/WallpaperManager(65):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:576)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16206535/1075066

Comment: If you are running the application on emulator, then try increasing the size of VM Heap by editing the emulator settings. Hope this might help you.

Comment: @Vincent I am not sure how to use this information since do not have any images in my app.  Would you please clarify?

Comment: @shree202 Yes, I am using the emulator and the RAM is set to 512 and VM Heap is set to 16 and thought that would be enough.  What would be a good number?

Comment: @SISLAM You're mistaken, i'm not talking about RAM. 512 is more than enough. I am talking about VM Heap. This option lies right next to the RAM field. Check once more, if you find it.

Comment: @Shree202 Ok, I have set VM Heap to 32 and I do not see the error any longer...Thank you so much.  I am still not sure why this is happening though.  The underlying issue still exists while I do not have any images/wallpapers in the app.

Comment: @SISLAM I faced the same problem. And I was given the same solution which i proved to you. I am running out of time since few weeks, so don't have the time to find out the root cause of this problem. May be i'll find it someday. Gud luck. Happy Coding.