# What does the term "VM" mean in the dreaded exception java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

For an analysis, I need to know **what the term `VM` means** in the dreaded exception:

> java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

This error is thrown when an application is running out of memory caused by a  [bitmap loading](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) (not efficiently).

Comment: VM usually means Virtual Machine

Comment: I know that VM is usually used for Virtual Machine, but the letter 'M' made me doubt. It can refer to the word "Memory"...

Comment: Android uses Java, thus runs within the JVM, or Java Virtual Machine. The page you linked to also has the words "Virtual Machine"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java code doesn't actually run on the hardware itself. Compiled Java bytecode runs on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine). The error you've encountered is telling you that the virtual machine it is running on has run out of memory.

As a solution to the problem, your best bet is to make sure that you're deallocating any images or large pieces of data you're using when you're done.

See: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)